# Prevent Middle Click button from opening new tab in FIREFOX not working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have the following simple code -I had a rather more sophisticated thing but this exemplifies my point-.

I have the below html

```
   <body>
    <a id="somelink" href="http://www.google.com" 
    onmousedown="preventOpen(event,this)" onclick="return 
    confirmClick();">Click me</a>
   </body>
```

And the following javascript code

```
  <script>
           function preventOpen(event, element){
               event = event || window.event;
               event.preventDefault();
               if (event.which != 3) {
                  element.click();
               }
           }

          function confirmClick(){
                return confirm("Are you sure?");
          }
  </script>
```

Basically, I'm trying to prompt for a confirmation if the middle click mouse wheel button is being used to open a new tab when clicking on the link -I want to prevent the new tab open-. This works in Chrome like a charm, however, it DOES NOT WORK in Firefox -the moment it exits the javascript code -namely the "confirmClick" function-, it opens a new tab-, although it triggers preventDefault() successfully. Any ideas on why this doesn't work in FF? I'd rather stay away from jQuery replies for now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the proper way to do this is using the `auxclick` event. ([auxclick on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event))

```
window.addEventListener("auxclick", (event) => {
  if (event.button === 1) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```